# How to fill this hex

Tags: opengl

I have a Hexagon done like this

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

//GRASS
glTexImage2d(GL_TEXTURE_2D,Level,Colorcomps,sGrass,tGrass,Border,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,background);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for I := 0 to 6 do
    begin
      glVertex3f(COS(i/6.0*2*PI)/10+offsetx+0.2,SIN(i/6.0*2*pi)/10+offsety,-2);
    end;
glEnd;
```

how do i now add the coords to add the texture to this?  Only way I have done it before was by setting them for each line.Like so `glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0);` Because this is in a for loop i cant do that. Is there another way? or do i have to remove the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the glTexCoord2f call in the loop, just above the glVertex3f call.

The coordinates to use depend on what you want. If you want all hexagons to have the same texture then give them all the same texture coordinates. The simplest case would be a square texture with the hexagon inscribed in it. The cords would be something like this:

glTexCoord2f(COS(i/6.0*2*PI)*0.5+0.5, SIN(i/6.0*2*pi)*0.5+0.5);

The hexagon cords go from -1 to 1, so multiplying by 0.5 makes them go -0.5 to 0.5. Then adding 0.5 makes them go from 0 to 1, which is what normalized texture coordinates are.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing stopping you from calling `glTexCoord2f()` from inside the loop, assuming you can compute the desired texture coordinates parametrically.

You should call it before the corresponding `glVertex3f()` gets submitted.

Comment: Yes but how to compute the coords?